# How to change Android button style temporarily after click?

Tags: android, button, styles

Please, suggest me some good practice to change button background color onclick(for few seconds). I use Android API 22.

[image: Button before click]

[image: after click]

Comment: What did you try so far? Please post any related code.

Comment: I ask for help to find out which style control responsible for such things, so I didn't try any code. If you now place in Android style guide where I can find an answer, please point me.

Comment: How about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few days back, so feel free to use my code.

```
Button myButton; //as a "global" variable so that it is also recognized in the onClick event.

myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b)
myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //set the color to black
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); //set the color to red
        // Delay of 2 seconds (200 ms) before changing back the color to black
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //set the color to black
            }
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is considered good practice though...

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this solution for Android API 21:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    final int redColor = 0xFFFF0000;
    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(redColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
        }
    }, 700);
}
```